# perl - matching at even positions and remove non-printable chars

Tags: perl

I have a hex2string from database table dump that is like

```
"41424320202020200A200B000C"
```

what I want to do is to match at the even positions and detect the control chars that could break the string when printed.. i.e remove ascii null \x00, \n, \r, \f and \x80 to \xFF, etc..

I tried removing ascii null like

```
perl -e ' $x="41424320202020200A200B000C"; $x=~s/00//g; print "$x\n" '
```

but the result is incorrect as it removed 0 from trailing hex value of space \x20 and leading 0 of newline \x0A i.e `20 0A` to `2A`

```
414243202020202A2B0C
```

what i wanted is

```
414243202020202020
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
say unpack("H*", pack("H*", "41424320202020200A200B000C") =~ s/[^\t[:print:]]//arg);
```

or

```
my $hex = "41424320202020200A200B000C";
my $bytes = pack("H*", $hex);
$bytes =~ s/[^\t[:print:]]//ag;
$hex = unpack("H*", $bytes);
say $hex;
```

or

```
my $hex = "41424320202020200A200B000C";
my $bytes = pack("H*", $hex);
$bytes =~ s/[^\t\x20-\x7E]//g;
$hex = unpack("H*", $bytes);
say $hex;
```

Solutions using `/a` and `/r` require Perl 5.14+.

---

The above starts with the following string:

```
 41424320202020200A200B000C
```

It is converted into the following using `pack`:

```
 ABC␠␠␠␠␠␊␠␋␀␌
```

The substitution removes all non-ASCII and all non-printable characters except TAB, leaving us with the following:

```
 ABC␠␠␠␠␠␠
```

It is converted into the following using `unpack`:

```
 414243202020202020
```

---

This solution is not only shorter than the previous solutions, it is also faster because it allocates far fewer variables and only starts the regex match once.

Comment: can you confirm that it will preserve tabs and spaces..I dont want to strip them..

Comment: Just add it to the list of chars to keep. (I've adjusted the answer)

Comment: could you please explain on the /a modifier, the solution works in my cygwin, but not sure it will do in my Enterprise Linux

Comment: It will work as long as you have Perl 5.14 or newer (for `/r` and `/a`). `/a` causes `[:print:]` to only match ASCII characters (00..7F).

Comment: Added alternatives that don't require 5.14. They'll work at least as far back as 5.6 (though you'll need to replace `say` with `print` before Perl 5.10).

Answer (score 2):

> detect the control chars that could break the string when printed.. i.e remove ascii null \x00, \n, \r, \f and \x80 to \xFF, etc..

Building on Hakon's answer (Which only strips out nul bytes, not all the other ones):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;
my $x="41424320202020200A200B000C";
say $x;
say grep { chr(hex($_)) =~ /[[:print:]\t]/ && hex($_) < 128 } unpack("(A2)*", $x);
```

gives you

```
41424320202020200A200B000C
414243202020202020
```

The character class `[:print:]` inside a character set matches all printable characters including space (but not control characters like newline and linefeed), and I added in tab as well. Then it also checks to make sure the byte is in the ASCII range (Since higher characters are still printable in many locales).

Comment: great answer.. I was building a regex with alternate matches and you have simplified it..

Comment: The active locale isn't consulted unless `/l` is used, so the last sentence doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to work directly with the hex form of the characters, but it's far more complicated. I recommend against using this approach. This answer serves to illustrate why this solution wasn't proposed.

---

You wish to exclude all characters except the following:

- ASCII printables (20<sub>16</sub> to 7E<sub>16</sub>)
- TAB (09<sub>16</sub>)

That means you wish to exclude the following characters:

- 00<sub>16</sub> to 08<sub>16</sub>
- 0A<sub>16</sub> to 1F<sub>16</sub>
- 7F<sub>16</sub> to FF<sub>16</sub>

If we group these by leading digits, we get

- 00<sub>16</sub> to 08<sub>16</sub>, 0A<sub>16</sub> to 0F<sub>16</sub>
- 10<sub>16</sub> to 1F<sub>16</sub>
- 7F<sub>16</sub>
- 80<sub>16</sub> to FF<sub>16</sub>

We can therefore use the following:

```
$hex =~ s/\G(?:..)*?\K(?:0[0-8A-Fa-f]|7F|[189A-Fa-f].)//sg;     # 5.10+

$hex =~ s/\G((?:..)*?)(?:0[0-8A-Fa-f]|7F|[189A-Fa-f].)/$1/sg;   # Slower
```

Comment: [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html). Matches where the last match left off (or at the start of the string if first match). You can imagine every pattern being prefixed by an implicit `\G(?s:.)*?\K`. By using `\G(?s:..)*?\K` instead, we advance by two positions instead of by 1 when looking for a match.

Comment: is it not redundant then?.. sorry it is little confusing to comprehend...

Comment: No, it's what prevents `00` from being matched in `2009`, the very problem you asked to solve.

Comment: For example, using `s/\G(?:..)*?\K00//sg` instead of `s/00//g` would have solved your problem if you just wanted to remove NULs.

Comment: in that case it would fail for very first occurence right?.. 004142?.. but it succeeds!!

Comment: Like I mentioned above, `\G` matches the start of the string on the first attempt (cause pos=undef=0 then).

Comment: both ````s/(?:..)*?\K00//g```` and ````s/\G(?:..)*?\K00//g```` gives the same results for the string ````"0041004200"````

Comment: And so does `s/00//g`. That doesn't make `s/00//g` and `s/(?:..)*?\K00//g` correct.

Comment: great! - I see the difference for the string "2009" as you mentioned.. so \G would be faster for my case as it will hop by 2 every time.. right?

Comment: Faster than what? The other solutions that first convert from hex? Yeah, but I wouldn't use this solution. I shouldn't have to tell you this; it should be evident how complicated it is just by looking at it. Complicated solutions are hard to read and hard maintain. This makes them error-prone and causes all sorts of problem. (In fact, there were three errors in the initial version of this answer.) The fastest solution is rarely the best, and the simplest solution is usually the best. (Of course, I'd take a fast and simple solution over a slow and simple one.)

Comment: yes.. I agree.. thank you for your time to explain all these stuffs.. learned a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can try split the string into 2 bytes substrings using [`unpack`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html):

```
my $x="41424320202020200A200B000C";
say $x;
say join '', grep { $_ !~ /00/} unpack "(A2)*", $x;
```

**Output**:

```
41424320202020200A200B000C
41424320202020200A200B0C
```

Comment: what is the ````13```` here ?.

Comment: it's the length of the string divided by two

Comment: I removed the fixed number 13. See my updated answer